# How to dynamically list document library titles onto a custom SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, publishing-page, highlighted-content-web-part

With SharePoint Online, if I have 7 document libraries within a site, titled like so:

```
food
keys
cars-2019
cars-2020
cars-2021
pets
family
```

...Is there a way I can dynamically list and link all my `cars_x` document library titles onto a custom SharePoint page, whenever a `cars_x` document library is created?

**Or**

On that custom SharePoint page, can I create a dynamic navigation menu that picks up and displays what I am trying to query?

I am trying to avoid manually writing out links, every time a document library is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Highlighted content web part** for your requirements like:

[image]

**Query text**:

```
contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary Title:"cars-*"
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Optional**:

Optionally you can set the layout & no. of items you want to show as per your requirements like:

[image]

Comment: Got it working...for a moment I thought the Title was part of the previous line, but its not.  it's is own line.  Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer & added query for others to copy paste directly.